# I am working with APIs and JSON on openweather.com. I created a URL to request Toronto weather data in Celsius. When I run html file, it shows nothing

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

When I run my html file,I am not able to fetch temperature from openweather.com

This is my html file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Lab: APIs</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Retrieving JSON Data from an API</h1>
        <h2 id="location"></h2>
        <div id="temperature"></div>
        <div id="conditions"></div>
        <div id="icon"></div>
         </div>
        <script src="LAB-11-APIs-22.js"></script>

> this is my javascript file

    </body>
</html>
```

This is my javascript file:-

```
function FetchAPI(city) {
    let key = '[my_api_key]';
```

> This is my api key

```
    let temp ="Celcius";
    
    var URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Toronto,On,Ca&appid=[my_api_key]";
```

> the URL I am using to fetch the weather.

```
let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
http.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        let json = JSON.parse(this.response);

        // ** EXTRACTING VALUES FROM JSON DATA SET **
```

> Give value to city's name

```
        document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = json.name;
```

> Display weather icon

```
        document.getElementById('icon').src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + json.weather[0].icon + ".png"; // STRING CONCATENATION
```

> Give value to temperature

```
        document.getElementById('temperature').innerHTML = Math.round(json.main.temp);
```

> Give value to conditions

```
        document.getElementById('conditions').innerHTML = json.weather[0].description;
        
        
    } else {

    }
}
http.open("GET", URL, true);
http.send();
}
```

Comment: What errors do you see in the console? Also, you shouldn't put your API key into a post like this; I'd recommend invalidating the key and requesting a new one from the provider. Finally, please make your comments into code comments so people can cut-and-paste the code more easily.

Comment: join all your ajax codes and post and why don't you use fetch ? anyways there are two possible problem one is your ajax code is breaking or your api is failing

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the function from the Javascript file?

Comment: where are you even calling your function?

Answer (score -2):

Call the function. For example,

```
  <script src="LAB-11-APIs-22.js"></script>
  <script>FetchAPI('Toronto')</script>
```

Your first `script` only defines a function but you never invoked it after.